# WSO2 IS Secondary userstore from ldap explorer

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have wso2 IS 5.3.0 with several user stores. I want to connect my app to the embebed ldap and access the user in the secondary user stores, but I only see the users in the primary user store.

How I can see the user in the secondary user stores con connect an application to the WSO2 IS ldap?

The aim is to have serveral user stored merged in just one, the IS ldap, and connect legacy applications to that merged LDAP. Is this approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this documentation[1] to configure multiple secondary user stores with WSO2 IS 5.3.0. Yes you can add multiple user stores to Identity Server and let the applications from outside see those as a single user store through Identity Server.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores

Comment: We already add the user stores using the management console, and I can see the 3 user store with their users, but when I connecto to IS ldap using ldap explorer, just see users from primary user store. The parameters I used to connect to the IS LDAP are: localhost/10389,   DN="uid=admin, uo=system"  password = admin. May I use some specific configuration to connect to the ldap to can see the whole set of users?

Comment: You cannot see secondary user store users if you directly browse internal LDAP. Internal LDAP (Apache DS) is another LDAP store embedded to Identity Server and by default acting as the primary user store. You can only see all the users through Identity Server. Identity Server does not copy secondary user store users to primary user store.

Comment: So, is there a ldap connector or whatever to achieve an LDAP interface that fetch all userstores for ldap legacy applications? Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes we have a connector for this [1]. But it is still under incubation. Feel free to use this connector and provide you feedback. The PR is still under review and will be merged within a day. Please create git hub issues if you face any.
[1] https://github.com/wso2-incubator/identity-inbound-provisioning-ldap

Comment: Will it be compatible with WSO2 IS 5.3.0? Any schedule for the stable version?

Comment: Yes it will. It is in the timeline but cannot exactly say the version.

Answer (score 0):

> May I use some specific configuration to connect to the ldap to can see the whole set of users?

Multiple user stores are completely separate, their own users, realm name, etc. In theory - your application you could use WSOIS API to access user information (with the realm prefix, such as usenr identity is `userstore_realm\username`

But as it is already mentioned in the comments, you don't see multiple LDAP stores as a single LDAP

> The aim is to have serveral user stored merged in just one, the IS ldap, and connect legacy applications to that merged LDAP. Is this approach wrong?

What could you do is "inbound" user provisioning. Effectively when a user is authenticated (using an external IS, secondary userstore, ...), the user could be provisionined ( [imported](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Secondary+Userstores+for+Inbound+Provisioning) ) to the primary userstore

Though it is possible, I won't recommend this approach as you will have duplicates out of control (e.g. when reseting the password)